# Clicking on cancel button in UISearchBar causes no selection in tableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I m using UISearchBar,and searching is working perfectly but after search clicking on cancel button, didSelectedRowAtIndexPath is not working in UItableView.It is not allowing me to select any row to go further.

Any Idea?

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
{
    isSearchOn = YES;
    canSelectRow = NO;
    table.scrollEnabled = NO;
}

- (void) doneSearching:(id)sender 
{   
    isSearchOn = NO;
    canSelectRow = YES;
    table.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;

    [table reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
    textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText 
{
    if ([searchText length] > 0) {
        isSearchOn = YES;
        canSelectRow = YES;
        table.scrollEnabled = YES;
        [self searchMoviesTableView:searchText];
    }
    else {
        isSearchOn = NO;
        canSelectRow = NO;
        table.scrollEnabled = NO;       
    }
    [table reloadData];
}

- (void) searchMoviesTableView :(NSString*)searchText{
    [searchResult removeAllObjects];

    for (NSDictionary *artistDic in listOfMovies) {
        NSRange titleResultRange = [[artistDic valueForKey:@"artist"] rangeOfString:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSLiteralSearch)];
        if (titleResultRange.length > 0)
            [searchResult addObject:artistDic];
    }
}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.text = @"";
    table.scrollEnabled = true;
    [table reloadData];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my mistake...

```
else {
    isSearchOn = NO;
    canSelectRow = NO;
    table.scrollEnabled = NO;       
}

set canSelectRow=YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are calling:

```
searchBar.text = @"";
```

in `searchBarCancelButtonClicked:`, which may lead to another call of `searchBar:textDidChange:`. In `searchBar:textDidChange:` you set:

```
canSelectRow = NO;
```

for strings whose length is 0 (which is true for `@""`). I wonder is that the root cause?

Comment: Thanks for giving answer but i can accept only one...! And I have got answer.